# Why does BarLegend change its position when exported?

Tags: plotting, export, legending

I have this code to create some `DensityPlot` with  M12.0.0.0 on Ubuntu

```
With[{z0 = 1, zm = 1}, 
 lgnds = BarLegend[{{Red, White, Blue}, {-zm, z0}}, 
   Ticks -> {{-zm + (zm/10), 
      Style[Text[-zm], Black, FontSize -> 14, 
       FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]}, {z0, 
      Style[Text[z0], Black, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
       FontSize -> 14]}}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 140, {LegendLayout -> "Row", 
    Charting`TickSide -> Right, TicksStyle -> None}]; 
 plot = Legended[
   DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, 
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, 
        Rescale[#, {-zm, z0}]] &), PlotPoints -> 80, 
    FrameStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Full, 
    AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {220, 390}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 30}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"", "Y"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
      FontSize -> 16}, GridLines -> {{20.5}, None}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
   Placed[lgnds, {{1, 1}, {1.15, 6.5}}]]]
```

and this what I see in Mathematica  where the `BarLegend` is correct

[image]

Now, I export this using `Export["/home/.../plot.png", plot,ImageResolution -> 500]` and this is what I got:

[image]

So, how can I keep the `BarLegend` position in the correct place when exporting?

Comment: `Placed[lgnds, Bottom]`

Comment: @cvgmt I want to place it at a specific position below the figure and `Bottom` does not do the job.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with 12.0.0 on macOS, but not with 12.1.1.

Comment: With 12.1.1 on Windows 10, I see the legend incorrectly placed (on top of the plot) in both Mathematica and in the exported png.

Comment: @MelaGo, it is working in wind. but you need to change    `Placed[lgnds, {{1, 0.86}, {1.15, 6.5}}]`

Comment: In Version 12.2, the "Ticks" in the BarLegend option is displayed in red, and the plot displayed in the notebook is similar to the unacceptable version in the OP's export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution to that seem trivial-:)
all we need to do is to replace `{1,1}` by `Bottom` in the `BarLegend[]`. So if we replace this in the original code `Placed[lgnds, {Bottom, {0.42, 0.3}}]` the figure in MMA and the exported one are the same.

```
With[{z0 = 1, zm = 1}, 
 lgnds = BarLegend[{{Red, White, Blue}, {-zm, z0}}, 
   Ticks -> {{-zm + (zm/10), 
      Style[Text[-zm], Black, FontSize -> 14, 
       FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]}, {z0, 
      Style[Text[z0], Black, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
       FontSize -> 14]}}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 140, {LegendLayout -> "Row", 
    Charting`TickSide -> Right, TicksStyle -> None}];
 plot = Legended[
   DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, 
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, 
        Rescale[#, {-zm, z0}]] &), PlotPoints -> 80, 
    FrameStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Full, 
    AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {220, 390}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 30}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"", "Y"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
      FontSize -> 16}, GridLines -> {{20.5}, None}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
   Placed[lgnds, {Bottom, {0.42, 0.3}}]]]
```

and this is how it looks in MMA

[image]

and exporting this gives the same plot also

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
With[{z0 = 1, zm = 1}, 
 lgnds = BarLegend[{{Red, White, Blue}, {-zm, z0}}, 
   Ticks -> {{-zm + (zm/10), 
      Style[Text[-zm], Black, FontSize -> 14, 
       FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"]}, {z0, 
      Style[Text[z0], Black, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
       FontSize -> 14]}}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 140, {LegendLayout -> "Row", 
    Charting`TickSide -> Right, TicksStyle -> None}]; 
 plot = Legended[
   DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 4}, 
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, 
        Rescale[#, {-zm, z0}]] &), PlotPoints -> 80, 
    FrameStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Full, 
    AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {220, 390}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 30}}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"", "Y"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
      FontSize -> 16}, GridLines -> {{20.5}, None}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
   Placed[lgnds, {{1, 0.86}, {1.15, 6.5}}]]]
```

[image: plot2]

Specifically:

```
Placed[lgnds, {{1, 0.86}, {1.15, 6.5}}]
```

I modified your Placed lgnds location...this exports this image with your bar below the image, like you want it. I also run  v12 on osx. If I remember correctly, `ImagePadding[]` is less than trivial and is likely what was causing the issue rather than `Placed[]`....I have had mannnny a broken image because of that function, with endless frustration...however I hope this fix, is quicker.

Comment: Indeed that will work but it does not solve the problem since the plot in the Notebook is not the same as the exported one

Comment: @HD2006 which version are you running? When i use your code, the plot in MMA was also broken.

Comment: M12.0.0.0 on Ubuntu

Comment: Bizarre...It may be a ubuntu thing? ...Also have you tried maybe just shutting down and restarting the kernal and running JUST that code you posted? I find when wonky things happen...it's because of something messing it up I forgot about.

Comment: I would also comment, the request was fixing the exported image, not your view in mma ;)

Comment: @morbbo, Yes I did restart the machine and different things, I want the picture in MMA and the exported one to be the same one